# Как запустить powershell в определенной папке

Tags: windows, cmd, powershell

Создал ярлык powershell консоли в Windows 10, хочу чтобы она запускалась от администратора и в определенной папке. Подскажите как сделать?

Я пробовал параметр запуска указывать, не работает:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -commnad 'cd F:\'
```

Также не работает рабочая папка в свойствах ярлыка: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уважаемые! у вас хорошие ответы, но они не подходят, я спрашиваю как мне запускать ярлык и попадать в папку с проектом. Т.е. я хочу щелкнуть по ярлыку и чтобы powershell открылся в нужно папке.

Comment: `-noexit -command "cd F:\\"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте PowerShell Profiles:

Находясь в Powershell дайте команду на создание профиля:

```
New-Item -ItemType file -Path $profile -Force
```

Откройте профиль на редактирование:

```
Ise $profile
```

Впишите в открывшемся редакторе команду перехода в нужный каталог:

```
cd F:\
```

Закройте консоль Powershell и попробуйте открыть снова. Вуаля - вы в папке `f:\`!

PS Статьи в помощь:

- [Профили в PowerShell](https://windowsnotes.ru/powershell-2/profili-v-powershell/)
- [All About PowerShell Profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2015/07/20/all-about-powershell-profiles/)

Answer (score 3):

В проводнике Windows перейдите в адресную строку (Alt + D или Ctrl + L). Введите powershell или powershell_ise и нажмите Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Заходите в папку, зажимаете клавишу `shift` + правую кнопку мыши и затем в контекстном меню нажимаете `Открыть окно команд` (или, наверное будет по другому написано - `Открыть Powershell`).

Answer (score 1):

Для powershell Core
`pwsh.exe -wd "c:\your_directory"`

Для powershell version <=5.1 (встроенная в windows)

Команда для реестра или при непосредственном запуске powershell
`powershell  -NoExit -command {Set-Location -Path "c:\your_directory"}`

Команда для "cmd подобных" ярлыки, запуск через bat файлы и другие варианты
`powershell -NoExit  -Command "& {Set-Location -Path \"c:\\your_directory\"}"`
или
`powershell -NoExit  -Command "& Set-Location -Path \"c:\\your_directory\""`
или
`powershell -NoExit  -Command Set-Location -Path "c:\your_directory"`

Для ярлыка конкретно
`"absolute_path\powershell.exe"  -NoExit -Command "& {Set-Location -Path \"c:\\your_directory\"}"`

Запуск от имени администратора, правая клавиша мыши - Запуск от имени администратора. Если хотите чтобы ярлык запускал сразу как от имени администратора, то свойства ярлыка=>дополнительно=>запуск от имени администратора или копайте в сторону команды runas и объединяйте команды.

Answer (score 0):

Можно, конечно, переписывать, но в первой ссылке первый ответ, которым я воспользовался. Редактирование реестра тоже помогло, пробовал

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183901/how-do-i-start-powershell-from-windows-explorer

https://www.iguides.ru/main/os/kak_otkryt_powershell_v_tekushchey_papke/

Comment: нет не нужно переписывать, это не подходит. я хочу передать параметры которые бы исполнились перед запуском ярлыка powershell.